# Seuqlize Migration Decimal(10,2) is converted to Decimal(10,0) with MySql

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

```
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable('Devices', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      uuid: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      user_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: 'user', // 'Actors' would also work
          key: 'id',
        },
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
        onDelete: 'SET NULL',
      },
      battery: {
        type: Sequelize.DECIMAL(10, 2),
      },
      brightness: {
        type: Sequelize.DECIMAL(10, 2),
      },
      rumble_intensity: {
        type: Sequelize.DECIMAL(10, 2),
      },
      fx: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      nickname: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(20),
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
    });
  },
  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('Devices');
  },
};
```

I am using Sequlize library version 6.12 and mysql2 library version 2.3.3.

The problem is DECIMAL(10,2) is converted to DECIMAL(10,0) and It doesn't apply onDelete: 'SET NULL'.
It is converted to onDelete: 'Restricted' which is default value.
I follow the documentation but it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have your dialect of database correctly set up?

Comment: And what version of MySQL do you use?